# How to combine two functions that only differ in parameter type

Tags: go, dry

So I have this golang function that looks like this:

```
func addDaysListener(ch <-chan []entity.Day, db *sql.DB) {
    for days := range ch {
        if len(days) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        logger := logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
            "ticker": days[0].Ticker(),
            "count":  len(days),
        })
        if err := update.InsertDays(db, days); err != nil {
            logger.Error(err)
        } else {
            logger.Info("Inserted Days")
        }
    }
}
```

I also have a function called `addMinutesListener()` that is identical EXCEPT:

- It listens on a `<-chan []entity.Minute`
- It calls `update.InsertMinutes()`

Both `entity.Day` and `entity.Minute` implement `datum.Candle`, although the update functions require the specific type. I'd like to write something like this:

```
func addItemsListener(db *sql.DB, ch <-chan []datum.Candle, insertFunc func(*sql.DB, []datum.Candle) error) {
    for items := range ch {
        if len(items) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        logger := logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
            "ticker": items[0].Ticker(),
            "count":  len(items),
        })
        if err := insertFunc(db, items); err != nil {
            logger.Error(err)
        } else {
            logger.Info("Inserted Days")
        }
    }
}
```

...Except the function signature for `update.InsertDays` and `update.InsertMinutes` both require the specific type, not the generic type, and the channels are set up like that as well. I could potentially change the channels, but I really can't change the insert functions because they do require the correct type as they insert the data into the database and the fields (properties) vary greatly between the two.

I feel like the correct answer to this problem may be something far more sinister, which is why I'm asking you, SO!

I'm sorry for the nondescript title; please feel free to comment if you have better ideas.

Comment: Presumably the else branch is different too. Just keep two functions, if you ask me. These functions are so small that removing a bit of duplication isn't worth the trouble of giving up static type safety or converting slice types elsewhere to work with a "unified" API.

Answer (score 1):

use type [assertions](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions)

```
func addDaysListener(ch <-chan []datum.Candle , db *sql.DB) {
    for days := range ch {
        if len(days) == 0 {
            continue
        }

        logger := logrus.WithFields(logrus.Fields{
           "ticker": days[0].Ticker(),
           "count":  len(days),
       })

     switch v:=days.(type){
       case  []entity.Day:
            if err := update.InsertDays(db,v); err != nil {
               logger.Error(err)
            } else {
               logger.Info("Inserted Days")
            }
       case  []entity.Minute:
            if err := update.InsertMinutes(db, v); err != nil {
               logger.Error(err)
            } else {
               logger.Info("Inserted Minutes")
            }

      }

   }
  }
```

Comment: I'm guessing the channel itself can at least commit to the type `<-chan []datum.Candle` in the function signature; the unchecked type assertion in the first line is risky.

Comment: simplified function signature suggested by David